# Storing multiple API keys for a user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm in the process of learning Django, and I'm building an app that has a "User" model, and I need to store a dictionary of private API keys for various other applications for each user, where the key is the service name and the value is the actual API key. My current plan was to have the dictionary be stored as JSON, but I was wondering if there is a better/more secure way I should be doing this?

Comment: Don't do that. Save in other model with foreigh key to user.

Comment: A separate model that can be extended in the future with other parameters that 3rd party APIs might need is much better indeed. And much more readable. But you ask about a 'secure' way... What do you mean by that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Use a extra Model with 1to1 relation to the default Django User Model (extendable, nicer)

2) Use a hashfield to secure the data
See https://github.com/amcat/django-hash-field

Comment: Ok, it looks like using an extra model is the way to go. Follow up question: shouldn't the new "API_Key" model have a many to 1 relation, if each "User" has multiple "API_Keys"?

Comment: You could do that of course but it would complicate the maintenance and readability as well as performance, e.g. one join. User ->1to1-> UserAPIAccess. You can extend this UserAPIAccess-Model as you go along. fb_api_key, twitter_api_key,...etc

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this answer. Hashing is not the same as encrypting. Hashing the API key doesn't allow you to retrieve that key in the future, which is necessary if it is actually to be used. In this case, the API keys are to be used for external applications according to the post, so hashing is not appropriate. Using a HashField here is *not* the answer. https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/difference-encryption-hashing-salting/

Answer (score -1):

djangomachine is right. Hashing is not the answer because you need to use the actual key at some point.

You need to encrypt the key upon storage and decrypt the key upon retrieval. Look into https://github.com/incuna/django-pgcrypto-fields for example.

Comment: This can be a comment and not a new answer. Also make sure the link is hyperlinked